# Qt: Compiler is out of heap space

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I received this error when I added more music my resources.qrc.  The mp3 files are not even that big, you have got to kidding me that this is all the MSVC compiler can handle.

Is there anyway around this?  Is it impossible to increase the heap space for a compiler?  I guess I can store the music and search for it locally, but then how do I deploy these resources to the phone?

Comment: You need to add more details, such as what OS you are developing on and for.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There's a workaround for this in Qt 5.4.0 : Use `CONFIG += resources_big` in your `.pro` file.

See also the 'rcc' section in the [5.4.0 changelog for qtbase](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/5367fa356233da4c0f28172a8f817791525f5457:dist/changes-5.4.0).