# Compiling 10MB+ resource files with qrc in cmake results in heap space allocation failures

Tags: cmake, qt5, qt-resource

I'm trying to compile large resource files with qrc using CMake.

This is well known to chew up all of a computers RAM (>32GB) and cause the compiler to exit with heap allocation errors (see [QTBUG-50468](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-50468), [QTBUG-55293](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-55293), and [QTBUG-54357](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-54357))

[Apparently if you use qmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28426240/qt-compiler-is-out-of-heap-space), appending `CONFIG += resources_big` to your .pro file [automagically fixes everything](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/interest/2016-March/021603.html). Is there an equivalent to this setting accessible through CMake?

Comment: Have you tried using [`AUTORCC`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/manual/cmake-qt.7.html#autorcc)?

Comment: @Torbjörn yes I am using `AUTORCC`.

Comment: I can't see any reference to passing `-pass 1` or `-pass 2` to rcc in Qt's CMake files, so I would say it's not supported yet. Please file a suggestion in Qt's bugtracker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are use the the build in cmake macros, just replace

```
qt5_add_resources(SRC_FILES resources.qrc) # normal resources
```

with

```
qt5_add_big_resources(SRC_FILES resources.qrc) # big resources
```

This requires Qt5.12 and CMake 3.9.

Answer (score 3):

I've filed bug report [QTBUG-55680](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-55680) and will update this answer once I hear back from Qt.