# Qt resource compiler: How to use "-t" option?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm running into a problem where the rcc compiler throws a "C1060: compiler is out of heap space"

Unfortunately I cannot use .pro files so am unable to use the following [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28426240/qt-compiler-is-out-of-heap-space?noredirect=1&lq=1) using the big resource flag

When looking for a work-around, I noticed the "-t" option in the [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/rcc.html) of the rcc compiler. It alludes to using this option when dealing with "big resources" but doesn't go into any details.

Can someone suggest how to actually use this option?

My current rcc arguments: `C:\Qt\Qt5.6.3\5.6.3\msvc2015\bin\rcc.exe -threshold 70 -compress -1   -name "%(Filename)" -o ".\_qt\win\qrc_%(Filename).cpp" "%(FullPath)"`

Comment: As the documentation states: `-t <file>` or `--temp <file>`. Did you try ? (perhaps I've misundertood you question)

Comment: @Fareanor Yes, I have tried giving it several file names and extensions, including cpp, rcc and qrc but it gives either an "Unknown error" or "Failed to read", it seems to make no difference whether these files exist or not. The question is more aimed at what the option actually does

Comment: @Tom which build system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the way I figured out how to use this option was to observe how Qt Creator calls `rcc.exe` when using `CONFIG += resources_big` in the `.pro` file. In the Compile Output view you can see the exact parameters used during the build.

Based on this, `--temp <file>` is part of a 3-step process so you can't really use it on its own. Let's assume that Visual Studio 2017 is used with Qt 5.12.7 on Windows 10, and the bin folders are in the Path. For simplicity's sake let's say you have a `cmd` open in you project folder, you have a build folder named `debug` there and a resource definition file `resources.qrc` which includes about 50MB of arbitrary data. In this case the 3-step resource compilation would look something like this:

```
rcc.exe resources.qrc -pass 1 -o debug/qrc_resources.cpp
cl.exe -c debug/qrc_resources.cpp -Fodebug/qrc_resources.tmp.obj
rcc.exe resources.qrc -pass 2 -temp debug/qrc_resources.tmp.obj -o debug/qrc_resources.obj
```

- Step 1 creates `debug/qrc_resources.cpp` which contains an empty
  array definition for 50MB data. This is a much smaller cpp file than
  what a more traditional rcc.exe call would generate (it would be ~300MB) since it does not
  include any actual data. This way cl.exe won't choke on a big cpp
  file.
- Step 2 compiles this cpp file into `debug/qrc_resources.tmp.obj`.
- Step 3 fills up the empty array in `debug/qrc_resources.tmp.obj` with the
  actual data that is defined in `resources.qrc` and outputs it into
  `debug/qrc_resources.obj`. This object file can then be used by the linker to
  create an executable or library.

If you use Visual Studio then Qt VS Tools version >= 2.5.0 can do this for you. You can set the Qt Resource Compiler as Item Type for the qrc file and set the Two-Pass Mode property to true.

Or you can try to create your own build steps based on the above code.